# android - Failed to add navigation dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, addition

I am trying to add navigation library in android studio but fails to add here is my build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.practice_8"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Comment: It would have been helpful to share the error message. If the error message is the title. it would have been nice to indicate so in the post itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your app/gradle, add

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

 def nav_version = "2.5.1"
```

inside  dependency{ } add

```
   // Kotlin
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

in project/gradle add

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
}
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.5.1"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
 }
```

and sync your gradle

Here is reference

> [Android Nav](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#groovy)